# No such file to load while running rake reek task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, reek

https://github.com/kevinrutherford/reek/wiki/Rake-Task

I followed all the instructions in the above page to install the reek gem and run it, but I get the following error while running the rake reek task.

```
rake reek
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- reek/rake/task

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

gem list --local (shows you the right gem to have been installed)

Comment: Do have the reek gem installed?

Comment: Yes, verified it through gem list --local

Comment: please post the error log do  `rake reek --trace` & put that error log here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from where you ran the task. But maybe this hint helps. You have to require reek/rake/task

```
require 'reek/rake/task'
```

see http://rdoc.info/github/kevinrutherford/reek/Reek/Rake/Task

And btw, the repository on github is now here:

https://github.com/troessner/reek